# Splitting RAID drives from ReadyNas Duo

Tags: network-attached-storage, raid1, readynas

I have an old ReadyNas Duo that is on its last legs and starting to play up. It currently has 2x 1TB drives inside, configured in a mirrored RAID 1.

I've just purchased an external caddy, and ideally I would like to pull one hard drive out, and hook it up via the caddy to a Raspberry Pi.

Is there any way to split the RAID, place the HDD in the caddy and retain the data? Or is it a question of starting again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory this is possible, but the formats are different on the hard drives so I had to re-format on one of them, then copy all the data back over